# Scikit learn linear regression predicting labels

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, linear-regression

I am trying to use SK learn to perform linear regression on time series labeled data.
My data format is `data=(timestamp,value,label)`

The labels that are assigned to my data are either 0 or 1.
I tried to follow this [example](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/linear_model/plot_ols.html) from SKLearn website

My questions:

1- Where are the labels of the training data in the example ? Are they in diabetes_y_train ?

2- What are the return values of the method [predict()](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html#sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.predict) ? In my code, it returns an array of n_samples as predicted values in the range [0,1]. However, I expected to have return binary values of either 0 or 1 (no intermediate values)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 - `diabetes_y_train` are the labels for train

2 - You are using a regression function, so it is right to have continous variables. If you want to have binary output you are not solving a regression problem but a classification one you can then set a threshold to discretise the predictions or use one of the [classifier](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/classification/plot_classifier_comparison.html) offered by sklearn.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help, I used SVC classifier and received the output that I needed.

Answer (score -1):

1 - Yes

2 - Predict calculates a floating point number, because the example is trying to predict a floating point value and not a binary value. So there is no yes/no answer, but a predictaed value, and to estimate the error, a difference is calculated and averaged in `np.mean((regr.predict(diabetes_X_test) - diabetes_y_test) ** 2)`